# Scripting VPN Credentials

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1, ras

I can easily create a VPN connection through the PowerShell command `Add-VpnConnection`, however it doesn't seem able to specify any credentials (there is no option to specify username/password). As a workaround I tried to use `-RememberCredential` option in `Add-VpnConnection` and to pass the credentials by forcing a connection through rasdial command, yet even though the connection succeeds Windows doesn't save the credentials :(

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name xxxxx ...
rasdial xxxxx user password
rasdial xxxxx /disconnect
```

Is it possible some way ?

Comment: If you do the connection manually (no PS) does Remember Credentials work? (related [question on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/521348/how-to-connect-with-a-vpn-connection-without-any-prompt-in-windows-8))

Comment: you should probably google a bit for the answer and post what you've googled and why they don't apply, if they don't apply. I've seen several related questions on SuperUser.

Comment: @Xpw yes to both your comments, but noone has not ever given an answer :) I have however solved using the dotras dll (see http://web2.codeproject.com/Articles/1158881/VPNScripter-a-scripter-for-Windows-VPN-connections) . Probably credentials can configured by specifying a particular xml configuration file in the EapConfigXmlStream field, but I was unable to find how to do it, if someone knows please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late, but I had same task and here is solution:

```
$vpnName = "YourVpnName"
$vpnServerAddress = "YourVpnServerAddress"
$vpnUserName = "YourVpnUserName"
$vpnPassword = "YourVpnPassword"
$vpn = Get-VpnConnection -Name $vpnName
if($vpn -eq $null) {
    Add-VpnConnection -Name $vpnName -ServerAddress $vpnServerAddress -TunnelType Pptp -EncryptionLevel Required -PassThru
    echo "vpn created"
}

if($vpn.ConnectionStatus -eq "Disconnected"){
        $cmd = $env:WINDIR + "\System32\rasdial.exe"
        $expression = "$cmd ""$vpnName"" $vpnUserName $vpnPassword"
        Invoke-Expression -Command $expression 
}
```

Comment: Tried the answer but get:
Remote Access error 703 - The connection needs information from you, but the application does not allow user interaction.

Comment: I tried your solution. But it is not save credentials.